# Can I remove iPad Keyboard 'hide keyboard' button?

Tags: ipad, keyboard

Looking at the iPad's UIKeyboard I'm noticing a 'hide keyboard' button in the bottom right, which I would very much like to get rid of. Is this allowed and possible? I'm not sure of the proper name for the button so google isn't helping me a great deal.

Many thanks

Comment: well, if I was making a UI class such as this, I would not let other programmers decide to lock out keyboard controls like that. Not with out require the program to have some elevated privileges first. The class is designed to bridge the application and the user, facilitating input. if the user decides to hide the keyboard he should be able to. if he still needs to enter something, then the application can request the keyboard is pulled out again.

Comment: a valid point. The behaviour differs from the iPhone version (where it was possible to present a keyboard with only a Done button) and I preferred this behaviour.

Answer (score -2):

You can't remove the "hide keyboard" button from the iPad standard keyboard, it's not permitted by Apple.

However, there is one way you can determine when the "hide keyboard" button is pressed:

```
- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
}
```

Comment: So, What do you think he is asking. Please let me know so I would like to solve his query.

Comment: The first two sentences of his question show exactly what he's asking, so you just need to read it.

Comment: @nil: I change my answer now. OK?

Comment: Looks good.  I think the bit about `textFieldDidEndEditing:` is probably irrelevant (@davbryn didn't ask about that), but I doubt it's really harming it.

Comment: It's wrong too. The docs say: "This method is called after the text field resigns its first responder status.". So it's not specific to the hide keyboard button.